# Serial code 00000000000 on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, serial-number

I'm trying to get the serial number of Samsung tablets. If I go to Settings > About device > Status the serial number shown is 00000000000. If I do the same thing on another Samsung device a different (probably correct one) serial number is shown.

In my app by using Build.SERIAL I can see that a serial number, different from 00000000000 is given. But if I use ril.serialnumber, again 00000000000 is shown. Can you explain me why does this happen and what does it mean if my serial number is 00000000000? 
Thanks!

Comment: blind guess: you sure yours is real Samsung not kind of chinese rip-off?

Comment: It shouldn't be.. Any ideas how to check?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an explanation about this. What I fount is that Build.SERIAL (as mentioned in the question) gives me the serial number and I noticed it is the same as the serial, get from ro.serialno.